# My lemon tree in pot has curled leaves

Tags: container-gardening, lemons

I live in Redwood city California. We bought this small lemon tree a year ago. About few weeks ago, it started flowering and new leaves coming. But then the new leaves started to curl. I thought it was lack of water, so I watered it more. But now the leaves are turning brown and dropping. Any ideas on what could be going on. I used to water it once a week, is that too little? Should I fertilize it now?

The plant is placed in a very sunny spot. We have been getting a lot of rain, but it is a sheltered spot.

[image: Lemon tree]

Answer (score 4):

If it has been in that same pot in the same spot for a year and just now started doing this, then fertilizer is one likely solution. Get a citrus fertilizer from your local garden center and follow the directions for potted plants. It is also possible it has become root bound and needs to be re-potted in a larger pot. If you do this, use citrus potting soil.

Answer (score 4):

I do see some leaves that have dropped and it may be due to the cold weather we are experiencing right now (I am in the same zone as you).  In terms of watering, check the soil and if it looks dry then water it more often.  Also, fertilizing would be a good idea.  I do see some flowers so that is a good sign and you may get some lemons soon.  Just keep watering and citrus fertilizer would help.  IF you can repot to a larger pot at some point, that may be a good idea.